# ApplyBulletDefault not applied in Do-Loop

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working in an Excel and filling out a word template (never done this before).
First I'm searching a column for a specific entry and then create a populate a bulletpoint with row-specific values. here is the code:

```
With wd.Selection
  .GoTo what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="launches"

  'Loop until cycled through all unique finds
  Do Until foundCells Is Nothing

    .Range.ListFormat.ApplyBulletDefault '<----- this doesn't work

    'Find next cell with value
    Set foundCells = Sh.Columns(2).FindNext(After:=foundCells)
    Name = foundCells.Offset(0, 3).Value & Chr(11)
    action = foundCells.Offset(0, 5).Value & Chr(11)
    .TypeText (Name & " " & action)

    'Test to see if cycled through to first found cell
      If foundCells.Address = FirstFound Then Exit Do
Loop
End With
```

As described I would like to create a bulletpoint for every cell I find. but the highlighted line doesn't work if it's in the Do loop, but works outside the Loop...Where's the problem?

**edit**:
before entering the above, I'm doing the following check for non-existing values:

```
Set foundCells = Sh.Columns(2).Find(what:=month)
'Test to see if anything was found
If Not foundCells Is Nothing Then
  FirstFound = foundCells.Address
Else
  GoTo NothingFound
End If
```

so there shouldnt be any issues regarding non-existing values (I hope)

Comment: can you put a line "msgBox(foundCells Is Nothing)" after (opt1) or before (opt2) "Do Until foundCells Is Nothing"? opt1: if there doesn't pop-up a messagebox, your foundCells variable is nothing. opt2: the messageBox will either show "true" or "false". if it's true, foundCells is nothing, if false then it should enter the loop and we'll continue finding your problem... ;)

Comment: @Kathara Thx for answer - I think I'm covering this... see edit

Comment: ok, how did you define the foundCells? As Range? as Cell?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to add the bulletpoint to the foundCells?

Comment: Could you maybe post the whole sub underneath your post?

Comment: You say that it works as long as that line is not in the do while loop. is this true? because it seems as if .ApplyBulletDefault is rather for Word than for excel and I can't find it being used in excel. Does it have to be bullets? What do you want to do with the foundCells? Wouldn't it be better to mark them with colours (background-colors, font-colors, borders)? Maybe even copy the cells (including row and/or column) and paste them somewhere?

Comment: (foundCells) is a range - and you're right: I want to populate the word document with a bulletpoint, then add some text to the bullet point (the text is coming from the Excel). I don't want to add any data to the Excel sheet, only generate a nice word-report from it.

Comment: Ok then there is an easier way... Do you only need the values from the found cells in your word-doc? Does that word-doc already exist or does it have to be generated?

Comment: @Kathara wow you are fast - I am loading a template and add a document: New Word.Application.Documents.Add(Template:=. ....)

Comment: and: I need a few cells from a few Sheets but nothing more, I just want to Loop through cells and populate the word template

Comment: What does the word-doc have to look like? Do the values from the found cells have to be a bullet list? And you're creating a new Word-doc from template? what does this doc include? are there any fields that have to be populated, a table or just a plain doc with some vba code?

Comment: Do you want your word doc to be automatically filled or do you want to copy and paste the found values?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152836/discussion-between-dv3-and-kathara).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this and tell me if it works?

```
With wd.Selection
  .GoTo what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="launches"

  .Range.ListFormat.ApplyBulletDefault '<----- this doesn't work    

  'Loop until cycled through all unique finds
  Do Until foundCells Is Nothing

    'Find next cell with value
    Set foundCells = Sh.Columns(2).FindNext(After:=foundCells)
    Name = foundCells.Offset(0, 3).Value & Chr(11)
    action = foundCells.Offset(0, 5).Value & Chr(11)
    .TypeText (Name & " " & action & vbNewLine)

    'Test to see if cycled through to first found cell
      If foundCells.Address = FirstFound Then Exit Do
Loop

End With
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help ;)